# View search by multiple values, how?

Tags: views, 6, search

Now I have built a search view and expose one parameter for user to filter search results.

The parameter is input via a textfield, i.e.:

```
 +------------------+
 | car              | [search]
 +------------------+
```

Is it possible to modify the above search view by:

- change the textfield to textarea
- such that user can input multiple values (one at each row)
- the filter will match *any* of the values entered
- and present results

i.e.:

```
 +------------------+
 | car              | [search]
 | magazine         |
 | 2012             |
 |                  |
 |                  |
 |                  |
 +------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to search through a view's node title field, node body field, or some other string field specifically, you may be able to customize the filter how you would like:

1. Add filter **Node: Title** or **Node: Body**
2. Set the Operator to **Contains any word**
3. Click **Expose**
4. Click **Update**

This will display a filter to the user that can filter the view by the corresponding field values that contain any of the entered words, separated by spaces. This does not format the textfield into a textarea, but works functionally as you had asked.